# Pod files not showing up on Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Anyone ever have their pod files not show up in their pod files?

Here is how my project's pods looks

[image]

and here is how they used to  look:
  [image]

I have ran '`pod install`' and it says everything is downloaded so I'm kinda at a loss. the error I am getting is error: No such module "Kingfisher"

---

EDIT:

Ok, so this kind of turns in to a different question. I had the .xcproject instead of the .xcworkspace. But I thought I had it backwards because when I open my workspace It keeps looking like this, and I can't open anything.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are opening the the `.xcworkspace` not `.xcodeproj`??

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue but I thought I had it backwards, my .xcworkspace looks weird though and I can't seem to run my code

Comment: Ok, I should pull this off, not sure how.. but I did view-> Show toolbar and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

In my case I did

```
pod init
```

and the Podfile got created (can see from terminal and finder) but not showing on currently opened Xcode project.

So, then I edited the Podfile with nano from terminal to install specific pods I need. Then I did:

```
pod install
```

And I got this message:

```
[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `FoodTracker.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 5 total pods installed.
```

Closing current project then re-open with new .xcworskpace will solve the issue.